# How to update progress bar while large math function executed (objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, uiprogressview

I have math function (about O^(10^7)) and while it searching result I have to display progress. So I have progress bar. The question is, how to update progress bar?
I have tried to do it so:

```
self.progressBar.progress = 0.0;
self->progress = 0.0;
for (1..10^7) {
    ...
    if (self.progressBar.progress < self.progress + 0.01) {
        [self updateProgress];
    }
}
[self updateProgress];
```

Comment: looks like it's unreal to write code on stackoverflow via iphone :(

Comment: - (void)updateProgress { [self.progressBar setProgress:self->progress animated:YES];}

Comment: i have tried to use performSelectorOnMainStream too.. and dispatch_async

Comment: dispatch added fun animation when result found)

Comment: Do calculation in background thread.  After each unit of your calculation, send a notification using nsnotificationcenter. Some object can then observe the notification and update the progress.

Comment: What does `O^(10^7)` mean?

Comment: in my country it's mean 10 000 000 operations or O^(10^7) time, where O - time for 1 operation

Comment: @Jeremy , exactly via NC?

Comment: I use this technique when download large files and I use indicator to show % complete.

Comment: @timurka13let I don't know what kind of notation is that, but it's confusing because it looks like [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Please don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the operation in a separate thread. That's a must.

Can you divide the operation into steps? Do you know the number of steps?
Then update progress bar after every step to `stepIndex/numSteps` percents.

If you can't divide the operation into steps but you know how long the operation will take, you can update the bar to `timeSinceStart/expectedTime` percents. Use a `NSTimer` for the periodic updates.

If you can't do that, use only a `UIActivityIndicator`, that is, a component that shows the application is doing something but showing no indication how long the operation can take.

Comment: I did it with performSelectorOnBackground (for calc.) and in background performSelectorInMainThread (for UI)!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to do:

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode (CFRunLoopCopyCurrentMode(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()), 0, FALSE);
```

To get the UI to update the progress bar.

Also.. you have animated:YES and that's not available in all versions of iOS.

You might want to consider instead in your updateProgress method:

```
if ([activityProgressView respondsToSelector:@selector(setProgress:animated:)]) {
    [activityProgressView setProgress:0.5 animated:YES];
}
else {
    [activityProgressView setProgress:0.5];
}
CFRunLoopRunInMode (CFRunLoopCopyCurrentMode(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()), 0, FALSE);
```